# How to redirect "println" commands output to a file in Groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

I would like to redirect out of println command which is details of job like Build name, status, time etc to another file.

Below is snippet of my code who's output i want to redirect to a file.

```
def lastBuildEnvVars = lastbuild.getEnvVars()
println 'Product Name : ' + lastBuildEnvVars['PRODUCT_NAME'] + 'Version : ' + lastBuildEnvVars['PRODUCT_VERSION'] + 'Result: ' + lastbuild.result + 'Time: ' + lastbuild.timestampString2 + '\n'
println 'Result: ' + lastbuild.result + '\nTime: ' + lastbuild.timestampString2
```

OutPut of println is

```
Current Product Name : OMA_KENAN_FX_READINESS
Product Version : 
Result: SUCCESS
Time: 2019-08-31T01:25:26Z
```

Comment: i don't know if it works in jenkins, but in usual groovy script you have just redefine out: `out=new PrintStream("/11/111.out", "UTF-8")`. after this all `println` commands will print to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    def logFile = new File("output.log")
    logFile.append('Product Name : ' + lastBuildEnvVars['PRODUCT_NAME'] + 'Version : ' + lastBuildEnvVars['PRODUCT_VERSION'] + 'Result: ' + lastbuild.result + 'Time: ' + lastbuild.timestampString2 + '\n')
    logFile.append('Result: ' + lastbuild.result + '\nTime: ' + lastbuild.timestampString2)
```

You can assign a line to a string variable and then do:

```
    def entry = 'Result: ' + lastbuild.result + '\nTime: ' + lastbuild.timestampString2
    println(entry)
    logFile.append(entry)
```

Then you could write a method called, say logIt(entry) that does the print and write to file:

```
    def logIt(entry) {
        //you have to let this method know about the file object somehow
        println(entry)
        logFile.append(entry)
    }
```

and so on and so on.